# Failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded when install prometheus helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kube-prometheus-stack

I am trying to install prometheus helm chart with default configuration in values.yaml

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

I face error "Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition". After that, I add a flag "--timeout" to increase time out

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --timeout 30m
```

Then the error is "Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded" with message "Job has reached the specified backoff limit". I log pod "prometheus-admission-create" during installation:

```
W0404 01:47:16.302029       1 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
{"err":"Get \"https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission\": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout","level":"fatal","msg":"error getting secret","source":"k8s/k8s.go:232","time":"2023-04-04T01:47:46Z"}
```

This is my events:

```
        LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                 OBJECT                                                    MESSAGE
    15m         Normal    Scheduled              pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml     Successfully assigned default/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml to dangln
    12m         Normal    Pulled                 pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml     Container image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6" already present on machine
    12m         Normal    Created                pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml     Created container create
    12m         Normal    Started                pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml     Started container create
    10m         Warning   BackOff                pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml     Back-off restarting failed container
    9m57s       Normal    Scheduled              pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7     Successfully assigned default/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7 to dangln
    6m29s       Normal    Pulled                 pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7     Container image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6" already present on machine
    6m29s       Normal    Created                pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7     Created container create
    6m29s       Normal    Started                pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7     Started container create
    4m53s       Warning   BackOff                pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7     Back-off restarting failed container
    15m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate       job/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create           Created pod: prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-pxhml
    9m57s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate       job/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create           Created pod: prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7
    75s         Normal    SuccessfulDelete       job/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create           Deleted pod: prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7
    75s         Warning   BackoffLimitExceeded   job/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create           Job has reached the specified backoff limit
    2m49s       Normal    FailedBinding          persistentvolumeclaim/storage-prometheus-alertmanager-0   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

This is my job desc:

```
Name:             prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create
Namespace:        default
Selector:         controller-uid=894df657-3d3d-4c09-9f5b-e59cc475bb28
Labels:           app=kube-prometheus-stack-admission-create
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=prometheus
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/part-of=kube-prometheus-stack
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=45.8.1
                  chart=kube-prometheus-stack-45.8.1
                  heritage=Helm
                  release=prometheus
Annotations:      helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
                  helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
Parallelism:      1
Completions:      1
Completion Mode:  NonIndexed
Start Time:       Tue, 04 Apr 2023 08:30:28 +0700
Pods Statuses:    0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=kube-prometheus-stack-admission-create
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance=prometheus
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/part-of=kube-prometheus-stack
                    app.kubernetes.io/version=45.8.1
                    chart=kube-prometheus-stack-45.8.1
                    controller-uid=894df657-3d3d-4c09-9f5b-e59cc475bb28
                    heritage=Helm
                    job-name=prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create
                    release=prometheus
  Service Account:  prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission
  Containers:
   create:
    Image:      registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      create
      --host=prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator,prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator.default.svc
      --namespace=default
      --secret-name=prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                    From            Message
  ----     ------                ----                   ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      12m                    job-controller  Created pod: prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete      3m28s                  job-controller  Deleted pod: prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-wljj7
  Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  3m28s (x2 over 3m28s)  job-controller  Job has reached the specified backoff limit
```

I consider changing backofflimit value in values.yaml file but I don't find the backofflimit value in that file. How to fix this error??

Comment: According to log, the container `create` has a problem.  Check the log during installation.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Without being able to see the text of the Job YAML and without knowing what program is running in the Pod it's hard to tell what might be going on.

Comment: Thanh you so much, I will edit image by code format later